# Looking for a specific release GDAL: 1.11.1 - Compiler: MSVC 2008 - Arch: x64

Tags: python, gdal, windows

I spent some time on gisinternals.com but I didn't find what I was looking for:

**GDAL: 1.11.1 - Compiler: MSVC 2008 - Arch: x64 - Python: 3.2:**

- *gdal-111-1500-x64-core.msi* (Generic installer for the GDAL core components)
- *GDAL-1.11.1.win-amd64-py3.2.msi* (Installer for the GDAL python bindings)

Does anyone have these two files in their archives ?

Answer (score 0):

The first is available after a plain Google search at https://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1500-x64-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4/gdal-111-1500-x64-core.msi

The second one seems superceeded by https://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1500-x64-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4/GDAL-1.11.4.win-amd64-py3.2.msi

I recommend you highly question your need for outdated, deprecated software though and use recent versions instead.